# imutils FaceAligner.align throws error: Can't parse 'center'. Sequence item with index 0 has a wrong type

Tags: python, imutils

This tries to do face-normalisation

This makes this error `Can't parse 'Center'`

```
import cv2
import dlib
from imutils.face_utils import FaceAligner
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

det = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
pred = dlib.shape_predictor(r'...\shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat')

alg = FaceAligner(pred, desiredFaceWidth = 256)

frame = cv2.imread('img.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
rect = detector(gray,1)[0]
faceAligned = aligner.align(frame, gray, rect)
```

The error comes from the `aligner`

```
File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\imgphon\landmark.py:94, in get_norm_face(frame, detector, predictor, aligner)
     89 rect = detector(gray,1)[0]
     91 # align face
     92 # TODO fork imutils, change this function to rotate and return the landmarks used for alignment; 
     93 # replace current marks_np
---> 94 faceAligned = aligner.align(frame, gray, rect)
     96 return faceAligned

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\imutils\face_utils\facealigner.py:68, in FaceAligner.align(self, image, gray, rect)
     64 eyesCenter = ((leftEyeCenter[0] + rightEyeCenter[0]) // 2,
     65     (leftEyeCenter[1] + rightEyeCenter[1]) // 2)
     67 # grab the rotation matrix for rotating and scaling the face
---> 68 M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(eyesCenter, angle, scale)
     70 # update the translation component of the matrix
     71 tX = self.desiredFaceWidth * 0.5

TypeError: Can't parse 'center'. Sequence item with index 0 has a wrong type
```

Comment: Please copy-paste the full error message into the post, including the stack trace. See [mre].

Comment: @CrisLuengojust this is error: TypeError: Can't parse 'center'. Sequence item with index 0 has a wrong type

Comment: **[mre] is required.** -- this is a bug in `imutils`. please contact Adrian Rosebrock to file a bug report. -- what's the value of `type(eyesCenter)`, what's the value of `type(eyesCenter[0])`? it should be a tuple of floats.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitzmy python skills is basic. Do you mean to convert the image,for example, into uint8? Is there a hacky way to sort this problem out? I badly need it.

Comment: https://github.com/PyImageSearch/imutils/issues